# Second Enemy object not acting like the first enemy

Tags: c#, xna

How come when I add a new Enemy object to my list of objects that are to be loaded into the game, the second one doesn't move around the screen like the first one?

**ObjList code**

```
class Items
{
    public static List<Obj> objList = new List<Obj>();

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        objList.Add(new Player(new Vector2(50, 50)));
        objList.Add(new Enemy(new Vector2(500, 500)));
        objList.Add(new Enemy(new Vector2(600, 200)));
        objList.Add(new BlueBall(new Vector2(300, 400)));
        objList.Add(new GreenBall(new Vector2(350, 100)));
        objList.Add(new OrangeBall(new Vector2(900, 250)));
        objList.Add(new PinkBall(new Vector2(100, 500)));
        objList.Add(new RedBall(new Vector2(600, 500)));
        objList.Add(new YellowBall(new Vector2(500, 250)));

    }
```

The third entry in the list is the second enemy that I wish to load into the game. The first one works as it should but the second enemy doesn't move around the screen like the first. Below is my Enemy class with the movement code.

**Enemy Class**

```
class Enemy : Obj
{
    float spd = 1;
    float detectionDistance = 175;

    public Enemy(Vector2 pos)
        : base(pos)
    {
        position = pos;
        spriteName = "BlackBall";
        speed = spd;
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        rotation = point_direction(position.X, position.Y, Player.player.position.X, Player.player.position.Y);
        speed = Math.Abs(Player.player.position.X - position.X) < 175 && Math.Abs(Player.player.position.Y - position.Y) < 230 ? spd : 0;

        base.Update();
    }



    public override void pushTo(float pix, float dir)
    {
        float newX = (float)Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(dir));
        float newY = (float)Math.Sin(MathHelper.ToRadians(dir));
        newX *= pix;
        newY *= pix;
        if (!Collision(new Vector2(newX, newY), new Player(Vector2.Zero)))
        {
            base.pushTo(pix, dir);
        }
    }

    //Uses Trig to calculate the shortest distance to the player then moves towards that position
    private float point_direction(float x, float y, float x2, float y2)
    {
        float diffx = x - x2;
        float diffy = y - y2;
        float adj = diffx;
        float opp = diffy;
        float tan = opp / adj;
        float res = MathHelper.ToDegrees((float)Math.Atan2(opp, adj));
        res = (res - 180) % 360;
        if (res < 0) { res += 360; }
        return res;
    }
}
```

The line `speed = Math.Abs(Player.player.position.X - position.X) < 175 && Math.Abs(Player.player.position.Y - position.Y) < 230 ? spd : 0;` is what the enemy is supposed to do, move towards the player if they get within a radius of 175 but this doesn't seem to be working on my second enemy and I can't see why.

**Objects are then updated in the Game1.cs**

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        foreach (Obj o in Items.objList)
        {
            o.Update();
        }
```

**Object Class**

```
class Obj : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    public Vector2 position;
    public float rotation = 0.0f;
    public Texture2D spriteIndex;
    public string spriteName;
    public float speed = 0.0f;
    public float scale = 1.0f;
    public bool alive = true;
    public Rectangle area;
    public bool solid = false;

    public int score;

    public Obj(Vector2 pos)
    {
        position = pos;
    }

    private Obj()
    {

    }


    public virtual void Update()
    {
            if (!alive) return;

            UpdateArea();
            pushTo(speed, rotation);
        }




    public virtual void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        spriteIndex = content.Load<Texture2D>("sprites\\" + spriteName);
        area = new Rectangle((int)position.X - (spriteIndex.Width / 2), (int)position.Y - (spriteIndex.Height / 2), spriteIndex.Width, spriteIndex.Height);
    }


    public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

        if (!alive) return;

        Rectangle Size;
        Vector2 center = new Vector2(spriteIndex.Width / 2, spriteIndex.Height / 2);
        spriteBatch.Draw(spriteIndex, position, null, Color.White, MathHelper.ToRadians(rotation), center, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

    }

    public bool Collision(Vector2 pos, Obj obj)
    {
        Rectangle newArea = new Rectangle(area.X, area.Y, area.Width, area.Height);
        newArea.X += (int)pos.X;
        newArea.Y += (int)pos.Y;

        foreach (Obj o in Items.objList)
        {
            if (o.GetType() == obj.GetType() && o.solid)
                if (o.area.Intersects(newArea))
                    return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Obj Collision(Obj obj)
    {
        foreach (Obj o in Items.objList)
        {
            if (o.GetType() == obj.GetType())
                if (o.area.Intersects(area))
                    return o;
        }
        return new Obj();
    }

    public void UpdateArea()
    {
        area.X = (int)position.X - (spriteIndex.Width / 2);
        area.Y = (int)position.Y - (spriteIndex.Height / 2);
    }

    public T CheckCollisionAgainst<T>() where T : Obj
    {
        // If collision detected, returns the colliding object; otherwise null.
        return Items.objList
            .OfType<T>()
            .FirstOrDefault(o => o.area.Intersects(area));
    }

    public virtual void pushTo(float pix, float dir)
    {
        float newX = (float)Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(dir));
        float newY = (float)Math.Sin(MathHelper.ToRadians(dir));
        position.X += pix * (float)newX;
        position.Y += pix * (float)newY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us the function that updates the list of objects

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp I have added the update of objects to the end

Comment: In push_To(): why are you assigning opp/adj to tan, wenn you never use that variable afterwards? And besides: what exactly does push_To()?

Comment: @Micha90 pushTo() is my method that moves the enemy towards the player, it works out the shortest route by using trig

Comment: Could you post the Obj-Class too? Is rotation a member-variable of Obj? And what is "trig"?

Comment: @Micha90 sure, I shall edit my post to include the Obj class. Trig = trigonometry

Comment: My initial thought would be that the speed that the second enemy has is 0 and thus not moving (from its distance from the player), what you can do is change your application type to a console application and write debug commands out to this to see the values (`Console.WriteLine`)

Comment: I agree, it may have something to do with speed = Math.Abs(Player.player.position.X - position.X) < 175 && Math.Abs(Player.player.position.Y - position.Y) < 230 ? spd : 0; where speed always get assigned a 0  by the ternary operator

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp I have the speed there set to 0 as they are stationary until the player gets within 230 pixels, it is only until then that they start to move, the 1st enemy is doing it but when I added the second, he doesn't move

Comment: What I can suggest you is to evaluate the two conditions and change the object color (green if true, red if false). This way, you will know if the problem lies there. Also, any reason why Obj is of Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game type ? And you may also consider using C# Properties instead of public variables.

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp I don't think there is any need for the Obj to be of Microsoft.Framework, what do you mean by using C# properties instead of public?

Comment: Your Obj class inherits from Microsoft.Framework.Game according to the code you provided. You can have a look at properties here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx. Properties enable a class to expose a public way of getting and setting values, while hiding implementation or verification code.